# correct way to obtain the rest of the parameters of URL in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cms

Hi everyone I am using  Django rest framework to create an API

In my URLs.py file I have this

```
  url(r'^cpuProjects/$', cpuProjectsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
  url(r'^cpuProjects/(?P<project_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', cpuProjectsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})),
```

This work perfectly, and I have this to url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad
```

in my retrieve function, I have this to get the parameter

```
  def retrieve(self, request, project_name=None):
    try:
      opc = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
      print(opc)
      ...
```

Now, I add this to my URLs.py files

```
url(r'^cpuProjects/(?P<project_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', cpuProjectsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})),


http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/name_project/whatever_string_here
```

My `print(opc)` in this last case return this `ad/pending`.

Is this the correct way to obtain the rest of the parameters of URL in Django rest framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that entire path of the url wrapped in this same regex named group. You can instead separate the trailing part by putting it in a different group:

```
url(r'^cpuProjects/(?P<project_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<status>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', ...),
```

And in your view:

```
def retrieve(self, request):
    try:
        opc = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        status = self.kwargs.get('status')
        ...
```